# Django - Cache vs QuerySet Filter for Server Efficiency?

Tags: python, mysql, django, caching

Which one of these two would be more efficient on server resources?

Lets say I have one "main" QuerySet that I use and then I have 3 additional filters to also display some filtered results.

**Option 1:**

```
q = Entry.objects.filter(filter='filter')
a = q.filter(filter=a)
b = q.filter(filter=b)
c = q.filter(filter=c)
```

**Option 2.**

Lets assume that I can cache the filtered results by memcached so now I can either run the Option 1 or I can do the following:

```
q = Entry.objects.filter(filter='filter')
a = cache.get('key_a')
b = cache.get('key_b')
c = cache.get('key_c')
```

Is it correct assumption that the Option 1 is just one database query and the the filters are applied by Django? Or am I wrong and by running the Option 1 the database get hit four times?

Now if the Option 1 = 1 database hit, is it more efficient to process the `a, b, c,` filters by Django (or rather the web server) versus just grabbing the results from the cache?

I would also cache the `q` results so technically I have these two options:

**Option 1a:**

Get the `q` from cache and apply QuerySet filters

```
q = cache.get('key_q')
a = q.filter(filter=a)
b = q.filter(filter=b)
c = q.filter(filter=c)
```

**Option 2a:**

get everything from cache

```
q = cache.get('key_q')
a = cache.get('key_a')
b = cache.get('key_b')
c = cache.get('key_c')
```

What is the correct, better approach for Django 1.8 running standard Linux/Apache/MySQL stack on AWS?

Comment: You need to benchmark to get the real answer.

Comment: An easy tool to check the number of database queries is [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). I believe Option 1 performs 3 queries. And next to that as far as I know a request to cache is a lot faster than a database query.

Comment: @jgadelange Thanks for the debug toolbar suggestion! I will definitely install it and it should help me to understand the Django queryset evaluation process. Any other handy tools you can recommend for Django development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it correct assumption that the Option 1 is just one database query
>   and the the filters are applied by Django?

No. The `filter(lookup=value)` calls are used to build the SQL `WHERE` clause.

> Or am I wrong and by
>   running the Option 1 the database get hit four times?

It's actually a bit more complex... Actually none of the four statements in option 1 result in a database hit, *until* you start iterating over the querysets. Then yes, you have (at least - cf below) one query per queryset, of course.

So mostly, caching an "unevaluated" queryset is pretty useless since at this point nothing has been loaded from the database.

NB: I say "at least one" because you can have N+1 queries if you start following foreign keys on your model instances (unless you built your queryset with the `select_related` clause).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! So now that I know that the `a, b, c` filters are 3 different query sets, at what point do they get executed? Is it by calling the `return context` in my view or is it the `{{ a.value }}` in the html template? Next question is if the `{{ a.value }}` or `{% for a in a %}` is called multiple times in the same template, is the query set executed again and again every time I call the `{{ a.value }}`? As per caching the queries, what is the best way to force the evaluation?

Comment: As I said, the query is executed when you actually try to access the records, either by iterating over the queryset, passing it to `list()` or `len()`, or do a direct access to a record (ie :`myqueryset[x]`). And the query is executed only once, results are cached in the queryset. So the simplest way to force full evaluation of the queryset is to iterate once over it, ie by passing it to `list`.